# My email is forcibly change from .com.sg to .sg even if hardcoded

Tags: javascript, php, email, opencart, cpanel

In my code I coded the email

```
<div class="infos">
    bake@pastrymart.com.sg
</div>
```

But in front end of my website still shows bake@pastrymart.sg removing .com.

Things I've tried:

- echoing it through php
- tried javascript .innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a PHP string replace function in your back-end, which is looking for any aliases like `pastrymart.com.sg` and replaces them with `pastrymart.sg`, and PHP string, and those JS, because the JS is although a part of PHP string.

You can try to use `%2E` instead of `.` like this `bake@pastrymart%2Ecom%2Esg`. Not the most stable way, but you can try it.

Although you can figure out where is those PHP rewrite function is and try to deal with it. It can be on the hosting provider level, or in your template controller.